# "to provide much details" vs "to provide many details"

Tags: grammatical-number

Which one is correct?

- *The guide doesn't provide **much** details*.
- *The guide doesn't provide **many** details*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The guide doesn't provide many details.

is both correct and fully natural.

The word "many" is typically used for a large number of individually separate items. The word "much" is typically used for a quantity of substance not readily considered as separate items.

> We didn't need much sand to fill the sandbox.

> The guide didn't give us much information about the town.

but

> We didn't need many boards to make the sandbox.